# Trying to update object's lookup field through lightning component inputField (List has no rows for assignment to SObject)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

So I am trying to create lightning component which changes my custom Object's (*MyTask__c*) `Lookup(Contact)` field from `lightning:inputField` which shows in my custom object page layout.

My custom object(*MyTask__c* haves `Lookup(Contact)` field.

I am getting **`Error message: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`** message in chrome console, even though I call

```
var action = component.get("c.changeTaskC");

action.setParams({"taskRecordId": component.get("v.recordId")});

action.setParams({"ContactId": component.find("firstContactId").get("v.value")});
```

as I should, the Apex Class still doesn't update MyTask__C record properly.

Here the code -

Lightning page :

```
<aura:component description="changeContact" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" controller="changeContact">

        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="MyTask__c" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Contact__c" aura:id="firstContactId" onchange="{!c.handleChange}"/>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning:button label="Choose Contact" type="submit" onclick="{!c.changeTasksContact}"/>
            </div>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>

</aura:component>
```

Lightning controller :

```
({
    handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var lookupId = event.getParam("value")[0];
    },
    handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        var record = event.getParam("response");
        console.log('handleSucess function');
        var apiName = record.apiName; // returns "Case"
        var caseId = record.id; // returns the Id of the new record
    },

    changeTasksContact : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.changeTasksContact_helper(component, event, helper);
    }
});
```

Lightning controller helper :

```
({

    changeTasksContact_helper : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.changeTaskC");
        action.setParams({"taskRecordId": component.get("v.recordId")});
        action.setParams({"ContactId": component.find("firstContactId").get("v.value")});
        console.log('Task Id' + component.get("v.recordId"));
        console.log('Contact Id' + component.find("firstContactId").get("v.value"));

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // Alert the user with the value returned
                // from the server
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());

                // You would typically fire a event here to trigger
                // client-side notification that the server-side
                // action is complete
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                            errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
});
```

Apex Controller :

```
public class changeContact {
    @AuraEnabled
    public string taskRecordId{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string ContactId{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void changeTaskC(string taskRecordId, string ContactId){
        MyTask__c taskToUpdate = [SELECT Id,Name,Contact__c FROM MyTask__c WHERE Id=:taskRecordId];
            taskToUpdate.Contact__c = ContactId;
            update taskToUpdate;
    }

    public static void updateTaskC(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the below is incorrect:

```
action.setParams({"taskRecordId": component.get("v.recordId")});
action.setParams({"ContactId": component.find("firstContactId").get("v.value")});
```

It should instead be:

```
action.setParams({
    "taskRecordId": component.get("v.recordId"),
    "ContactId": component.find("firstContactId").get("v.value")
});
```

Comment: Could you explain why this action behave like that? And also thanks for answering this

Comment: Has nothing to do with the action in particular. When you call `setParams`, it sets your entire parameter list to what gets passed in. So your second call just completely wipes out the first.